# Jquery stops working after post and html()

Tags: html, post

I have a html page with rows of items. Each item pops up a dialog box with tabs into which the user can add data. When they hit save, I run this code, which refreshes the item:

```js
  function reloadRecord(actionSelector) {
 $.post("ReloadRecord.do", {
  id: actionSelector.find("input:hidden[name='id']").val() 
  }, function(html){
      actionSelector.closest(".itemWrapper").html(html);
    }, "html"); 
}
```

For some reason, though, this code kills the jquery elements in the popup, when it is opened again - the tabs, datepicker, and note popup.

Is there a way I can refresh all the jquery elements? Doing the following makes the tabs work again, somewhat, but there are too many elements to deal with individually.

```js
function reloadRecord(actionSelector) {
 $.post("ReloadRecord.do", {
  id: actionSelector.find("input:hidden[name='id']").val() 
  }, function(html){
      actionSelector.closest(".itemWrapper").html(html);
      **actionSelector.find('.alrt-bar.tabsOpened-after').each(function(){
       $(this).tabs();
      });**
    }, "html"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap all jQuery initialization code in a function and then call it each time you reload an item.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, @ShmiliBreuer!